# Find top k nearest points in numpy arrays of x and y coordinates

Tags: scipy, gis

Am using KDTRee to find nearest points in Python as follow:

```
ckdtree= scipy.spatial.cKDTree(A)
pt0 = [6, 30]  
pt0_distance, idx0 = ckdtree.query(pt0)
```

Just wondering to find the top k closest points of pt0 using Tree...